# apachectl start can't find httpd but it is there?

Tags: apache-2.2, linux, web-server, configuration

Just configured and installed Apache (successfully as far as I know) on a remote server, via X-Win32 SSH.

In the bin directory I see "httpd" listed.

To start the web server my provided instructions for the server state:

> From your installation Apache directory type, './bin/apachectl start'.

However, I get the following error (11-14 just showing it is there):

```
server.edu(11): ls
bin     cgi-bin conf    htdocs  icons   include libexec logs    man     proxy
server.edu(12): cd bin
server.edu(13): ls
ab              apxs            dbmmanage       htpasswd        logresolve
apachectl       checkgid        htdigest        httpd           rotatelogs
server.edu(14): cd ..
server.edu(15): ./bin/apachectl start
./bin/apachectl: apache/bin/httpd: not found
./bin/apachectl start: httpd could not be started
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your distro there are other commands to try:

```
service httpd restart
service apache2 restart
```

What distro are you using?

Comment: also `which apachectl` `which apache2` `which httpd`

Answer (score 1):

As I see, you have installed apache manually and it was mis-configured somewhere, because apachectl tries to launch apache/bin/httpd,  which does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are already at apache directory, if httpd is in bin directory, you will be able to run httpd by ../apache/bin/httpd.